# Library uses localStorage - Chrome Web Store

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-app

So yes Chrome has its own local storage API. I used

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"item": itemValue});
```

and

```
chrome.storage.local.get("item", function (result) {
     console.log(result);
});
```

For all my storage calls.

The problem I face is I have developed a HTML5 game with Phaser.js and it includes localStorage statement somewhere inside of it, which doesn't allow me to view my game at all. So Instead I get this error in console:

```
window.localStorage is not available in packaged apps. Use chrome.storage.local
```

and a black screen.

What would you do in this case? I don't develop Phaser.js
Is there some functionality I could turn off in Chrome/API or I just don't bother with Chrome Web Store at all?

Comment: you don't have to be the developer of the library to change it. at the very least you need to figure out what it uses localStorage for ao you know what will break when using the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to load this code before you load Phaser.js :

```
window.localStorage = undefined;
```

Or :

```
window.localStorage.getItem = undefined;
```

Comment: Yes this worked :D Will leave it a bit for further thoughts on the question.

Comment: Yes, that also probably broke the app in subtle ways.